# Custom assistive touch

Tags: ios, assistive

Is it possible to create an app (App A) with a programmatically created view that works very much like Assistive Touch: stays on top of the UI, and is visible pretty much anytime (while using App B, App C etc)?

Objective is to be able to make screenshots in random parts of the interface and then launch an app that can process these screenshots (from camera roll or wherever else).

Comment: Not unless you're Apple. Pretty sure there's some minor security detail with your app running over and taking screenshots of my banking app.

Comment: fair enough, but all actions are user-controlled

Comment: But there's no way to enforce that from an OS/security perspective. What "user controlled" means is that you run your screenshotting function in response to a user touching a button. There is nothing preventing a malicious developer from running that same screenshotting function from a timer, or based on particular on-screen content. Consequently it's completely prohibited.